# Given MNIST files (images and labels) in gz. How to read them in numpy.ndarray?

Tags: python, mnist

I have no idea what to do with the given files minst gz files. Basically, I want to be able to read them in numpy.ndarray but have no idea how.

I want to try reading from the given files rather than importing and all from other libraries like sklearn or keras. Please help me.

Comment: Your question doesn't reveal anything about what's in the files, just that they are compressed, so I just picked a common duplicate. If you have a more specific question, please [edit] to explain in more detail what you have tried and where exactly you are stuck. It should not be hard to find existing questions about processing the MNIST dataset where you can see how others have approached it. If you still need more help, describe in more detail what result you are looking for.

Comment: Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71175143/how-to-read-and-display-mnist-dataset and the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].